# Different font sizes for Figure and Subfigure Captions

Tags: captions, fontsize, subfloats

That's what I use

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

The template I'm using is from a university and uses the Koma Script
When adding figures or graphs I do this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}[normal]{0.40\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/Fig1}
\caption{Caption of Fig1}
\label{Label of Fig1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[normal]{0.40\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/Fig2}
\caption{Caption of Fig2}
\label{Label of Fig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is the caption for whole graphic}
\label{This is the label for the whole graphic}
\end{figure}
```

what I want to know is how to simply adjust different font styles for the captions of the `subfigures` and `figure`.

I want especially the captions fonts of the `subfigures` to be smaller than the captions fonts of the `figures`.

As far as I googled the problem, I could do this with a `Koma` script command or by addressing the `caption` package.

I tried the following:

```
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}}
```

this affects all captions but how can I adjust the captions of subfigures separately?

I don't understand the difference in the approaches between the `koma`Script and the `caption`packages
So I simply want to adjust the Font sizes of the different Caption types separately and uniquely for the whole document and I would like to adjust the space between the captions and the subfigures .....

Comment: BTW: `[normal]` is not a valid position specifier for the `minipage` and `subfigure` environment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `[sub]` optional parameter of `\captionsetup`, e.g.

```
\captionsetup{font=normalsize,labelfont={bf,sf}}
\captionsetup[sub]{font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}}
```

BTW, I would add a `\centering` in your `figure` environment.

Comment: This doesn't work for me for figures created with `figure*`. If I manually put `\captionsetup{...}` within a specific`figure*` environment, it works - but I'd like to do it once at the beginning of the document, so that when you put it at the start, it works not only for `figure`, but also `figure*`. Any help with that?

Comment: @Ela782 I've just tried and it works for me with `figure*` too. I suggest you ask a new question and provide a couple of details. You can link to this question in order ot provide some background.

Comment: I see, thanks for trying! It is my particular setup then. I will proceed as you suggest. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't you have to do `\usepackage{caption}` first?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Wow, I didn't remember I wrote this answer. Anyway yes, the `subcaption` package is required, but this is clear from the question setup so I wrote only the relevant snippet.

Answer (score 1):

When I was Googling, I first thought that the title was complaining about the behavior and not trying to reach the behavior. Since some people might understand the question the same as I understood, I will add a way of putting the same font size for both: caption and subcaption. Depending on your LaTeX configuration, you will not be able to get smaller fonts with the same size for the figure and subfigures (I had such a behavior in my thesis). To reach the desired font size for the figure environment, just put in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize}
```

For the subfigure's caption size to be taken into account, just change the command figure from

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
```

to

```
\begin{figure}[h!]\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize}
```

The `footnotesize` in `font=footnotesize` can be changed only by the following sizes:

```
* \Huge
* \huge
* \LARGE
* \Large
* \large
* \normalsize
* \small
* \footnotesize
* \scriptsize
* \tiny
```

> P.S.: You can use the \captionsetup command in the preamble as well.